# Can costmap_2d's static_map be updated?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, costmap, global-costmap, static-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am working on implementing the navigation stack on a robot, and was wondering about the update behaviour of costmap_2d.

My global costmap is receiving a 2D SLAM map from Cartographer over the /map topic. Does this map update, and if yes how frequently?

So far [this](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap) was the only documentation I managed to find, which was written way back in Hydro, so was wondering if the interface has remained the same. I have gone through the official wiki tutorials as well as the [tuning guide](http://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf) by Kaiyu Zheng, would much appreciate more of such guides :)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356491/can-costmap_2d%27s-static_map-be-updated?/) by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2020-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-07-06**:
To me it seems (never checked) that the map parameter "static" uses a service instead of a constantly published topic to get the map only once. When using regular published topics the same behaviour seems to be possible with map_topic and first_map_only parameters set. I seem to remember that the parameter subscribe_to_updates means that changes in the map (slam) are transported in the sub-topic updates and added to the map (not a full new map is received). What works for you is dependent on your setup. The usual navigation stack (gmapping, amcl) uses the map_server thus service, thus static map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The static map will update at any rate as new maps come in (its a callback, not polling) as long as you have `subscribe_to_updates` parameter set to true.

For ROS2, we have a number of parameter guides https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/index.html

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2